# Hibernate Identifier generator sequence and MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

Can someone point me in the right direction here.

Does Hibernate support MS SQL 2012, sequences as a

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

Looking to port from Oracle to MS SQL trying to figure out what won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported yet but there's a pull request about this: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/395